# Lines inside a shape

Tags: visual, pattern

**All four objects follow a certain pattern. First three are complete, fourth one isn't. Your task is to complete the fourth object. Explain why it's correct.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Box 1 indicates that the RED lines

> are forming POLYGONS. (We see a Pentagon, Hexagon, and Heptagon)

Box 2 indicates that the BLUE arrows

> are clueing LETTERS. The 10 sides and arrows starting from only 3 adjacent nodes suggest the arrows start at 0, 1, or 2, and end at 0-9, forming a 01-26 AZ encoding. For example, an arrow starting at 0 going to 1 is 01 = A
>  [image: numbered figures]

Decagon 1:

> 01 A
>  20 T
>  14 N
>  05 E
>  15 O
>  16 P
>  07 G
>  these are the letters found in PENTAGON

Decagon 2:

> 01 A
>  24 X
>  14 N
>  15 O
>  05 E
>  07 G
>  08 H
>  HEXAGON

Decagon 3:

> 01 A
>  20 T
>  14 N
>  15 O
>  05 E
>  16 P
>  07 G
>  08 H
>  HEPTAGON

Decagon 4:

> This "isn't complete" which implies it is partially complete, meaning it shows a red DECAGON completely obscuring the black decagon outlining each figure.
>  (Alternatively this was meant to be black and we are supposed to draw a red OCTAGON, the next shape in the sequence, although this would also introduce an ambiguity of which vertices to connect).
>  To complete the DECAGON, we need the following arrows:
>  04 D
>  05 E
>  03 C
>  01 A
>  07 G
>  15 O
>  14 N
>  As pictured here:
>  [image: decagon]

Comment: This is correct, good job!